# How to separate string input in two, and use the second one to open/create file, to read and write

Tags: c, readfile, minesweeper

I am doing a program that reads user input files (coordinates) and it creates a minesweeper mini-game, with bombs placed at given coordinates.
My problem is with the read option, the input should be: read filename.
I am trying to separate the string in two, but I'm not doing great.

ps. I'm a beginner so I probably made stupid mistakes, and the code is a mess right now because it's not finished.

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define map_SIZE 25
void mapa(void);
void printUsermap(void);
void readf(void);
void bombmaker (void);
int x, y, i, j;
int numbers;
char mines;
char map[map_SIZE][map_SIZE];
char final_map[map_SIZE][map_SIZE];
char umap[map_SIZE][map_SIZE];

void mapa(void){
    int column, row;

    
    for(column = 0; column < map_SIZE; column++)
        for(row = 0; row < map_SIZE; row++)
            umap[column][row] = '_';
}

void printUsermap(){
    int column, row;

    system("cls");

    for(column = 0; column < map_SIZE ; column++)
    {
        for(row = 0; row < map_SIZE; row++)
        {
            printf("%c", umap[column][row]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
        
    }
void bombmaker (){
    int i=0, j=0;
    if( map[i][j] != '*')
            {
                map[i][j] = '*';
                final_map[i][j] = map[i][j];
                mines++;
            }
}

void readf(){
    
    char string[50] = "practice try.ini ";
       // Extract the first token
       char * token = strtok(string, " ");
       // loop through the string to extract all other tokens
       while( token != NULL ) {
          printf( " %s\n", token ); //printing each token
          token = strtok(NULL, " ");
       }
//reading second string
    /*char buff[128];
     int i = 0;
     scanf("%s",buff);
                
      char *p = strtok (buff, " ");
      char *div_var[2];
      while (p)
     {
      div_var[i++] = p;
       p = strtok (NULL, " ");
       }

       for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
      {
        printf("data[%i] = %s\n", i+1, div_var[i]);
       }

    char ch, file_name[25];
    printf("> ");
      gets(file_name);
    
       FILE *fp;
        fp = fopen(div_var[1], "r"); // read mode

       if (fp == NULL)
       {
          perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       printf("The contents of %s file are:\n", file_name);

       while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
          printf("%c", ch); */
}
    
int main()
{
  char option[128];

  // MENU
  printf("+-----------------------------------------------------\n");

  printf(" read <filename>     - read input file\n show                - show the mine map\n trigger <x> <y>     - trigger mine at <x> <y>\n plant <x> <y>       - place armed mine at <x> <y>\n export <filename>   - save file with current map\n quit                - exit program\n sos                 - show menu\n ");

  printf("+-----------------------------------------------------\n");
    
    
  do{
    printf(">");
    scanf ("%s", option);


    //Opcao read
      //if (strcmp(option, "plant")!=0 || strcmp(option,"tigger")!=0 || strcmp(option, "show")!=0 || strcmp(option, "export")!=0 || strcmp(option, "quit")!=0){
      if (strcmp(option, "read")==0){
          
          readf();
      }
  


    // Option show

    if (strcmp(option, "show")==0)
    {
    mapa();
    printUsermap();
    }

    // Option trigger


    else if (strcmp(option, "trigger")==0)
    {
      scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
      if (x >= 25 || y >= 25){
      fprintf(stdout, "Invalid coordinate\n");
      }
      else if (map[i][j] == '.'){
      map[i][j] = '*';
      final_map[i][j] = map[i][j];
      mines++;
      }

      else{
      fprintf(stdout, "No mine at specified coordinate\n");
      //fprintf(stdout,"Hello. My name is Inigo Montoya. You killed my father. Prepare to die\n");
      }
    }

    // Option plant

     

    else if (strcmp(option, "plant")==0)
    {
      scanf("%d %d", &x, &y);
      if (x >= 25 || y >= 25){
      fprintf(stdout, "Invalid coordinate\n");
      }
      else if (map[i][j] == '_'){
      map[i][j] = '.';
      final_map[i][j] = map[i][j];
      mines++;
      }

      else if (map[i][j] == '*'){
      map[i][j] = '.';
      final_map[i][j] = map[i][j];
      mines++;
      }

      else{
      //printf ("You're gonna need a bigger boat\n");
      }
    }

    // Opcao export
    else if (strcmp(option, "export")==0)
    {
        FILE * fp;
        fp = fopen("file1.text","w");
        fprintf(fp, "teste");
        fclose(fp);
    }

    // Opcao SOS
    else if (strcmp(option, "sos")==0)
    {
      printf("+-----------------------------------------------------\n");

      printf(" read <filename>     - read input file\n show                - show the mine map\n trigger <x> <y>     - trigger mine at <x> <y>\n plant <x> <y>       - place armed mine at <x> <y>\n export <filename>   - save file with current map\n quit                - exit program\n sos                 - show menu\n ");

      printf("+-----------------------------------------------------\n");
        
    
    }
  }

  while (strcmp(option,"quit")!=0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char buff[128];` this does not contain anything valid, what are you parsing here? and its not clear what your question is, you should consider asking particular question clearly

Comment: Please format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using `scanf`. Read in the input with `fgets`. Then use `strtok` (or better `strtok_r`) to first split of the action.  If the action is "read", you can then split of the filename in `readf`.

in `main`:

```
char line[256];
fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
char *action = strtok(line, " \t\n");
```

in `readf` you can then get a the filename parameter with

```
char *filename = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
```

Error handling was ommited for brevity.